# Running multiple SET statements in CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

using SQL 2012

I have a CTE statement that give me incorrect results.  Multiple records for each record_id may exist with different types.  This seems to be skipping records and not updating all of them correctly:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT
        o.sname, o.type, o.record_id, 
        p.data1, p.data2, p.data3

    FROM
        table1 p
        JOIN table2 o ON o.record_id = p.record_id
    WHERE
        o.record_id IN(1,2,3)
        --AND (o.type = 123 or o.type = 456 or o.type = 789)       

UPDATE cte
set data1 = (case when type = 123 then 1 else data1 end),
data2 = (case when type = 456 then 1 else data2 end),
data3 = (case when type = 378 then 1 else data3 end)
where type in (123,456,789)
```

Not sure why this happens.

What I am after is to look at only certain records and if a specific TYPE value exists, change the DATA value to 1 every time it is encountered for specific TYPES.

If I run the UPDATE part of the CTE this way, it works correctly, just not when together:

```
UPDATE cte
    set data1 = (case when type = 123 then 1 else data1 end),
    where type in (123) 

UPDATE cte
    set data2 = (case when type = 456 then 1 else data2 end)
    where type in (456)

UPDATE cte
    set data3 = (case when type = 789 then 1 else data3 end)
    where type in (789)
```

Whats wrong?

Here are Tables and desired outputs:

```
TABLE1      
record_id   |type   |sname
------------|-------|-----|
1           |123    |alpha
2           |123    |alpha
2           |456    |beta
3           |456    |beta
3           |789    |gamma
```

Table 2 is originally all zeros

```
Desired Output:         
TABLE2          
record_id|  data1|  data2|  data3|
---------|-------|-------|-------|
1        |1      |   0   |   0
2        |1      |   1   |   0
3        |0      |   1   |   1
```

Actual Output:

```
TABLE2          
record_id|  data1|  data2|  data3|
---------|-------|-------|-------|
1        |1      |   0   |   0
2        |1      |   0   |   0
3        |0      |   1   |   0
```

Thanks,

MP

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you try to do? Perhaps show some sample data and expected output. I'm confused by the (apparent) aliases `t` and `o`, what do they relate to?

Comment: I updated my post, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use aggregation in a subquery to check which type exists for a given record_id and then multitable update like this:

```
update t2
set t2.data1 = t1.data1,
    t2.data2 = t1.data2,
    t2.data3 = t1.data3
from table2 t2
join (
    select record_id,
        max(case when type = 123 then 1 else 0 end) as data1,
        max(case when type = 456 then 1 else 0 end) as data2,
        max(case when type = 789 then 1 else 0 end) as data3
    from table1
    group by record_id
    ) t1
    on t1.record_id = t2.record_id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NHFN52228)

Another way is using correlation with `EXISTS`:

```
update t2
set data1 = case when exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.record_id = t2.record_id and t1.type = 123) then 1 else 0 end,
    data2 = case when exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.record_id = t2.record_id and t1.type = 456) then 1 else 0 end,
    data3 = case when exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.record_id = t2.record_id and t1.type = 789) then 1 else 0 end
from table2 t2;
```

#### [Demo 2](http://rextester.com/CPA16503)

Comment: Ah ha!  I had a feeling I was missing something like this!  I will try it, thank you!

Comment: Well, its not working correctly, it is changing some values correctly, but not correctly, its missing some???

Comment: Yes, not working.  If there is more than one record with the same TYPE data in the resultant CTE, it skips the next one.  So if I see records with more than one say TYPE = 123, it does not process the next record properly.  ???  If I run each CASE line separately by itself, it works fine.

Comment: @mrpush - It does what you asked. See this demo - http://rextester.com/HVTO7340 .If that's not what you want. Please update the question properly with sample input data and expected result.

Comment: @mrpush - Please add sample table data and expected output in your question. May be create a fiddle at http://rextester.com

Comment: @mrpush - Also, make edits to the question. Don't replace the whole thing with code from an answer. It invalidates any existing answer.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a bit new to this forum format.  I added tables and desired and actual.  thanks

Comment: OMGosh! Man your a genius!  Worked first try!  Thank you Thank you Thank you! ( I used the latter one)